# Returning other entry in the url includes the first entry as well

Tags: laravel

```
public function show(Criminal $criminal){
        $profile = Criminal::with(['profile','crimes'])->findOrFail($criminal);
        dd($profile);

}
```

I have this method and it should return like this when I type localhost:8000/criminal/1

[image: The image]

But when I say like criminal/3

it also returns the criminal/1 json output like this :

[image]

the first entry looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function show(Criminal $criminal, $id){
    $profile = Criminal::with(['profile','crimes'])->findOrFail($id);
    dd($profile);

}
```

Comment: How did you get on fixing this problem? Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to query the database again, the model passed to your function is already an eloquent model.

```
public function show(Criminal $criminal) {
    dd($criminal);
}
```

---

If you really want to [lazy load the relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading), this can be done as follows:

```
public function show(Criminal $criminal) {
    $criminal->load('profile', 'crimes')
    dd($criminal);
}
```

This should not be necessary however as Laravel loads relations when needed.